# Has Amazon Web Services‎ removing credit card option changed?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was using AWS almost two years ago and as I remember I was able to remove my default payment method from `amazon.com` but now I see that I can't remove my default payment method. [This page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/edit-payment-method.html#remove-credit) says:

> Ensure that your account has another valid payment method set as the default

Am I remembering it wrong or has it changed in this year?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, according to [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/remove-default-payment-method/) the policy has changed.

Currently you can not have an active account without a default payment method.

Comment: Can you (briefly) summarize, using blockquotes `>` for anything that you use verbatim, the information at the page, please?